# Checking checkbox A, triggers checkbox A & B. But checking checkbox B should only trigger checkbox B in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, checkbox, vuetify.js

I have two checkboxes in **Vuetify**. I'm trying to write them in a way that if I check checkbox A, it automatically checks both checkbox A & B. But clicking on checkbox B triggers only checkbox B. What's the best way to do it?
Here is my code:

```
<v-checkbox label="A" value="A" v-model="A"> </v-checkbox>

<v-checkbox label="B" value="B" v-model="B"></v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few solutions to handle it.

1. You can use [Vue watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

> ```
> <template>
>   <div>
>     <v-checkbox label="A" v-model="A"> </v-checkbox>
>     <v-checkbox label="B" v-model="B"></v-checkbox>
>   </div>
> </template>
> <script>
>   export default {
>     ...
>     watch: {
>       A: function (newVal) {
>         if (newVal) {
>           this.B = true
>         }
>       }
>     }
>     ...
>   }
> </script>
> ```

2. Using `@change` event on `v-checkbox`